# Trabalhar com campo BLOB no ORACLE usando Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle, blob

Possuo um sistema onde irá armazenar determinados arquivos em uma coluna do tipo BLOB no meu banco de dados ORACLE, porém não encontrei nada a respeito na documentação do próprio Codeigniter de como fazer isso, como posso manipular esses arquivos, onde preciso alimentar essa tabela e também exibir o arquivo que está armazenado nessa tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Eis um exemplo de como atualizar uma coluna BLOB com um arquivo recebido via upload. O segredo é a concatenação de `0x` com a transformação em string do conteúdo binário para hexadecimal.

```
public function updateColunaBlob($id_cliente, $file_name, $file_data) {
    $this->db->set('FILE_NAME', $file_name, false);
    $this->db->set('FILE_DATA','0x'.bin2hex($file_data), false);
    $this->db->where('ID_CLIENTE', $id_cliente, false);
    $this->db->update('CLIENTES');
}
```

Mas, se por ventura, o arquivo for muito grande e não há possibilidade de configurar pra maior este limite, dá para fazer o mesmo upload de pedacinho em pedacinho, sem perda quanto ao conteúdo. Exemplo para MySQL, qual ao invés de `0x` utiliza apenas `X` diante da string hexadecimal. Aqui de maneira bem explícita; não está sendo usado query builder e a coluna é atualizada de 512 Kb em 512 kB:

```
public function updateColunaBlob($id_cliente, $file_name, $file_data) {
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['nome_arquivo_upload']['tmp_name'], "rb");
    $contents = '';
    $i = 0;
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $contents = fread($handle, 512000);

        if(!$i)
            $this->db->query("
                UPDATE
                    CLIENTES
                SET
                    FILE_NAME = ?,
                    FILE_DATA = X?
                WHERE
                    ID_CLIENTE = ?
            ", array($file_name, bin2hex($contents), $id_cliente));     
        else
            $this->db->query("
                UPDATE
                    CLIENTES
                SET
                    FILE_DATA = CONCAT(FILE_DATA, X?)
                WHERE
                    ID_CLIENTE = ?
            ", array(bin2hex($contents), $id_cliente));     
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```